# change clicked li width using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a listing item like a gallery and all my li are sitting at 30% width and float, anyway what i want to do is if i click a specific li i only want THAT li to change to 100% width obv the others will fall under it but than clicking an X should bring it back to 30% width and so wld clicking another LI and end result switching all other LI to 30% and the Li i selected to be at 100% width.

what i want to accomplish is to let the li i selected which only shows full width and height image at 30% to take up full width of the gallery and display hidden content such as item info. therefore:

setting image width to fixed width displaying content next to it
expanding li width to 100% of box.
then reversing action when closing the Image using an X or another Li (IF Function)

Here is a code snippet too much coding to display here

```css
  
#gallery{
 background-color:#0f0;
 display:block;
 width:80%;
 height:80%;
 min-width:180px;
 border:#060 solid 1px;
 text-align:center;
 position:fixed;
 position:absolute\9;
 margin-top:5%\9;
 top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop))\9;
 top:10%;
 left:10%;
 /* Box shadow */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#006600', Direction=112.7, Strength=5);
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;
 box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;
}
#gallery h1{
 background-color:#060;
 width:95%;
 min-width:150px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#0f0;
 border-top:#060 solid 1px;
 border-bottom:#060 solid 1px;
 margin:5% 0px 3% 0px;
 /* Box shadow */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#111111', Direction=112.7, Strength=5);
 -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;
 -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;
 box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;
}
#gallery ul{
 background-color:#080;
 width:100%;
 height:80%;
 padding:10px 0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border-top:#040 solid 1px;
 border-bottom:#040 solid 1px;
 display:block;
 overflow:scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
#gallery li{
 width:30%;
 height:200px;
 border:#090 solid 1px;
 margin:10px 1.3%;
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 /* Box shadow */
 -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;
 -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;
 box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
    <h1> Browse Our Gallery 
        <a href="javascript:gallery()" style="font-size:29px;color:maroon;background-color:#050505;padding:5px 10px;float:right;margin-top:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">
            X
        </a>
    </h1>

    <ul>
        <li name="item1"><a href="javascript:list(item1);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item2"><a href="javascript:list(item2);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item3"><a href="javascript:list(item3);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item4"><a href="javascript:list(item4);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item5"><a href="javascript:list(item5);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item6"><a href="javascript:list(item6);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item7"><a href="javascript:list(item7);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item8"><a href="javascript:list(item8);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item9"><a href="javascript:list(item9);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item10"><a href="javascript:list(item10);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item11"><a href="javascript:list(item11);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li name="item12"><a href="javascript:list(item12);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

So what i come up with is applying a javascript onclick with list()
and do something like `document.getElementBYtag` or something like that sorry not familiar with javascript than only changing the Li tag i selected as being part of an if as if its like

```
function list(){
    var li = specific code to select only the li im selecting and not all LI;
    IF(Li.style.width === 30%){
        li style.width = "100%";
    }else{
        li.style.width = "30%";
    }
}
```

even if it means using Name or value but not id otherwise i have to style every LI with diff id names

even INNERHTMl attribute wld be appriciated but please don't give me jQuery or using other libraries just javascript or plain css even obv the thing needs to work in IE8 or higher.

Comment: If you only adjust the width of a float, in some cases the expanded `<LI>` element will be moved lower on the screen. To avoid this, you might need to use absolute or static positioning.

Comment: The idea is to let the other floats fall underneath the full width  list because after selecting the image it should produce the image in a fixed width and hidden content next to it so the other images are just ment to flow underneath it

Comment: The floats that precede the one you expanded in will still be shown above it. only the subsequent floats will fall below. This means that if the user clicks on a float in the middle of the row, the expanded float will be displayed below the images that were previously to the left of it.

Comment: I noticed that which is fine my only concern is if more than one li is expanded it becomes confusing thats y only one li should be displayed at full width meaning my other li should be reset when clicking a new one

Comment: I found out what u said may have to be taken into consideration as it does look abit messy without aligning the element to be first maybe i can consider a X axis galler that acts as a slider? just hate having to rely on X axis as this site is run on mobile too

Comment: NVM i found out why  the X wasnt working i accidently removed the javascript function it LOL sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');

function active(){
  if(this.className.indexOf('active') > -1){
    li.forEach(function(e){
    e.classList.remove('active');
  })
  } else {
    li.forEach(function(e){
    e.classList.remove('active');
  })
    this.classList.add('active');
  }
}

li.forEach(function(e){
 e.addEventListener('click', active, false)
});
```

```css
#gallery{
 background-color:#0f0;
 display:block;
 width:80%;
 height:80%;
 min-width:180px;
 border:#060 solid 1px;
 text-align:center;
 position:fixed;
 position:absolute\9;
 margin-top:5%\9;
 top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop))\9;
 top:10%;
 left:10%;
 /* Box shadow */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#006600', Direction=112.7, Strength=5);
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;
 box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;
}
#gallery h1{
 background-color:#060;
 width:95%;
 min-width:150px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#0f0;
 border-top:#060 solid 1px;
 border-bottom:#060 solid 1px;
 margin:5% 0px 3% 0px;
 /* Box shadow */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#111111', Direction=112.7, Strength=5);
 -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;
 -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;
 box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;
}

#gallery ul{
 background-color:#080;
 width:100%;
 height:80%;
 padding:10px 0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border-top:#040 solid 1px;
 border-bottom:#040 solid 1px;
 display:block;
 overflow:scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

#gallery li{
 width:30%;
 height:200px;
 border:#090 solid 1px;
 margin:10px 1.3%;
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 /* Box shadow */
 -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;
 -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;
 box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.active{
 width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
    <h1> Browse Our Gallery 
        <a class = "reset-btn" href="javascript:gallery()" style="font-size:29px;color:maroon;background-color:#050505;padding:5px 10px;float:right;margin-top:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">
            X
        </a>
    </h1>

    <ul>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item1"><a href="javascript:list(item1);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item2"><a href="javascript:list(item2);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item3"><a href="javascript:list(item3);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item4"><a href="javascript:list(item4);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item5"><a href="javascript:list(item5);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item6"><a href="javascript:list(item6);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item7"><a href="javascript:list(item7);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item8"><a href="javascript:list(item8);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item9"><a href="javascript:list(item9);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item10"><a href="javascript:list(item10);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item11"><a href="javascript:list(item11);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
        <li class = "list-item" name="item12"><a href="javascript:list(item12);"><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: This idea works but now the giant X isnt working if u need the script for it here: function popup(){
var email = document.getElementById('email-blast');
var fade = document.getElementById('fade');

if(email.style.display === "block"){
 email.style.display = "none";
 fade.style.display = "none";
}else{
 email.style.display = "block";
 fade.style.display = "block";
}
}

Comment: That giant X should reset all images to width 30% is that what you saying?

Comment: No the giant X closes the gallery that is open the gallery acts as a popup when i click the button on my page it popsup the gallery box the thing im editing and inside the gallery is items but images when the image is clicked it expands to 98% i had to change it as it overlaps the scrollbars. so clicking the X just closes the gallery but now using the function ignores it :(

Comment: and also it undoes the li when clicking the li i need to be able to undo it on click also is there like and extra line of code i can use to undo the click after?

Comment: I'm confused now your X button triggers some gallery() function that I do not see anywhere. The script you provided is popup() function for some different id's  'email' and 'fade' which has nothing to do with the gallery.

Comment: NVM i found out why the X wasnt working i accidently removed the javascript function it LOL

Comment: I gave u the wrong function but they are the same its just the Id names are different sorry about that :(

Comment: Your answer does the trick it resets other Li when clicking one other but doesnt reset when clicking the same li again which is also what i may need if i add order button inside thx and Rounin expands and resets the li when clicking the same li but doesnt reset the other li which cause abit of confusion :( so urs is working great thx :)

Comment: Thx man i cant Up posts since i dont have enough reputation points yet but if im happy with the results i'll say done thx :)

Comment: Hey i also found out that ur function for selector selects all the Li in the page and almost everything in my page is using li and ul coz i use the css hide and unhide attribute use input checkbox which doesnt work on IE8 so thats y im looking into javascript :)

Comment: That is why you should  use classes. I have updated the snippet to target only those li's.

Comment: Also make sure you do not have that same class (list-item) nowhere else in you html.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work on IE 8? because classList doesnt work on IE8??? and is there also a way to take that selected li and make take it to the top and than revert it when clicking a diff li im sorry if im asking too much

Comment: There might be a way to get this work in IE 8. Include following script in your Project and see if it woks : https://github.com/moagrius/classList/blob/master/classlist.js

Comment: No sorry i tried it doesnt work and i dont know why i cant view developer tools just says its open but there is nothing there :( I did check which of the elements u used that doesnt support IE 8 there is 3 elements that dont work  its classList, ForEach and AddEventListener we have to use AttachEvent in place of the event listener and querrySelector only works with css 2 in IE8

Comment: i solved the moving li up when clicked i just change the position to absolute and created a invisible div at the top i just want to know how to add the hide an unhide class into that function so it only takes up space when clicking the li and not already taking up space im gonna just create a css hack where a message will be displayed to anyone using IE8 to update or use a seperate design pretty simple no need to use javascript there just make a div thats naturally display:none than make display:block\9;

Comment: alright i think im gonna have to put this to an end ur answer by far helped me but now i descovered safari has issues too so i think we should wrap this up and say this answer by far helped all browsers except Old IE and safari im gonna try something different and see what other ideas i can use thx for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

One approach here is to use the `classList` API.

if you have a class:

```
.full-width {
width: 100%;
}
```

Then you can deploy the following javascript:

```
function toggleFullWidth() {
    this.classList.toggle('full-width');
}

var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', toggleFullWidth, false);
}
```

---

**N.B.** This is not a "doing your homework for you" answer. This is to give you enough of an idea to get started and produce the effect yourself.

Comment: Sounds interesting can u explain what the javascript does? or can u refer me to the site u got the answer of if u made the answer please Im new to it and it sounds interesting to learn :) just the for part of the function needs explaining i understand it shifts the Li tag to apply class but the parent selector prevents other stylings to work unless i apply !important to it

Comment: `var listItems` is a nodelist of your `<li>` elements. The `for loop` cycles through the nodelist and attaches an event listener to each element. The event listener triggers the function.

Comment: so what is the function? meaning it changes to the class or id named full-width?

Comment: The function uses the `classList.toggle()` method (other `classList` API methods include `classList.add()`, `classList.remove()` and `classList.contains()`). `classList.toggle()` looks at the classes currently attached to an element and if the class in question is present, it is removed and if the class is absent it is added.

Comment: I see so it just switches to the class if its not already there and removes the class when its not thx :) but the problem with it is it doesnt reset the other li back to 30% just brings it to 100% and brings back if clicked again is there a way to tweak it so that it resets the li that was selected before it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. And given that you know about the `classList` API... what do you think that way might be? You have all the information you need to crack this puzzle. Give it some thought and you will solve it. Hint: you will need `classList.remove()` as well as `classList.toggle()`.

Comment: Hey i found out the class list attribute isnt supported on IE less than version 10 and i need it to run version 8 and up

Comment: i had another idea is to create an li that already is styled with the class and just use javascript to move the selected li content to that li that way it will also stay at the top its just a thought is it possible? and wld it be supported on IE 8?

Comment: It continually amazes me what IE doesn't support. I gave up supporting IE in 2010 - I concluded it was like trying to produce color television programs for a black and white TV set. Instead of `classList` (which is a `DOM TokenList`) you can use `className` (which is a `string`) - `className` is a _DOM Core Level 2 Property_ and is supported all the way back to IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to iterate over all the `li` elements in your `#gallery` and attach the `click` event listener.

In the event handler with a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) update the `el.style.width` attribute.

Code:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('#gallery ul li')
  .forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      el.style.width = el.style.width === '100%' ? '30%' : '100%';
    });
  });
```

```css
#gallery{background-color:#0f0;display:block;width:80%;height:80%;min-width:180px;border:#060 solid 1px;text-align:center;position:fixed;position:absolute\9;margin-top:5%\9;top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop))\9;top:10%;left:10%;/* Box shadow */filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#006600', Direction=112.7, Strength=5);-webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;-moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #060;}
#gallery h1{background-color:#060;width:95%;min-width:150px;padding:10px;font-size:20px;color:#0f0;border-top:#060 solid 1px;border-bottom:#060 solid 1px;margin:5% 0px 3% 0px;/* Box shadow */filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#111111', Direction=112.7, Strength=5);-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #111;}
#gallery ul{background-color:#080;width:100%;height:80%;padding:10px 0px;margin-bottom:10px;border-top:#040 solid 1px;border-bottom:#040 solid 1px;display:block;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;}
#gallery li{width:30%;height:200px;border:#090 solid 1px;margin:10px 1.3%;float:left;display:inline-block;/* Box shadow */-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;box-shadow:-1px 0px 15px #020;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <h1> Browse Our Gallery 
  <a href="javascript:gallery()" style="font-size:29px;color:maroon;background-color:#050505;padding:5px 10px;float:right;margin-top:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">X</a></h1>

  <ul>
    <li name="item1"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item2"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item3"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item4"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item5"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item6"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item7"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item8"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item9"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item10"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item11"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
    <li name="item12"><a><img src="Front-card.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I like what is happening here but is there a way to undo the li when clicking a diff li coz when clicking multiple li just expands them which isnt a bad idea but im wondering if it can like reset all other li and only keep the one i select expanded

Comment: I also found out that the code doesnt seem to work on IE8 it says Item1 undefined??? just refers me to the very first line of my html document

Comment: Compatibility for Internet Explorer 9+

Comment: Thx for the effort i appriciate it but i need it to work on IE 8 as the most of my target audiance MAY be using IE8 and so far everything is working on IE8 Except this idea which really isnt bad :)